# Passing arguments to a shell script from C# process

Tags: c#, linux, process, plink

I am stuck with a problem from many days.

I am connecting to a linux box and want to run some scripts and collect back the file generated.

Steps are
1) connect
2) run some scripts (which are interactive and need inputs at some point)
3) get the file generated as a result.

1) I am connecting to linux box through plink.exe (commandline version of putty.exe) this step is successful.

2) I am able to run scripts but when the scripts run it expects some input, i am not able to figure out how to pass these inputs to the script. what happens is the program hangs as the scripts does not complete.

These inputs are fixed and vary between certain values, i can hard code these values into application / program.

Please help me in doing this.
Thanks in advance
-Akash

Comment: If plink is unsuccessful you'll need to solve that first. Can you give us any more information - the error, how you're calling plink, how you've set up your SSH server?

Comment: on bash shell, we do run like $scriptname <arguments>
So see if ur plink has such argument passing API support

Comment: Hi Rup, Plink connection is working fine. I am able to connect to server and run commands. Earlier we where using putty.

Comment: could you please clarify, why if Plink is working fine, you say that this step is unsuccessful? What is unsuccessful about it? Is there a error message?

Comment: Hi Zespri, Sorry for the confusion by mistake i had written it unsuccessful. Sorry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "YourFile.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "";//Arguments should be here
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

you can use **exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();** to get the results

Comment: Hi Navid,  Thanks for the reply. I have tried this approach, but its not working. In start.Info.Arguments i have passed the arguments which are used during connection time.

Comment: I used this Arguments="plink mysession echo hello, world"; and the result gets hello, world