# Need to understand how to run a simple shell script in a azure vm lunix

Tags: c#, api, shell, azure-functions, azure-virtual-machine

I was following this documentation and trying to run a shell script in a VM using this:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtual-machines-run-commands/run-command

My first question is: when I use a simple script, example 'ls' in input of the post method, I get status 202 and no result message, can any one please tell me why?

My second question is: I want to run a script file `myscript.sh` and pass some parameters to it. But I don't know how to pass a paramter to a script in input

Can anyone help me to understand or show me how to do it, I'm using .NET and C#.

This is my code right now

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    Body body = new Body
                    {
                         commandId = "RunShellScript",
                         script = new List<string> { "ls"}
                    };

    // Generate Bearer Token
    var azureServiceTokenProvider = new AzureServiceTokenProvider();
    string managementApiUrl = "https://management.azure.com/";
    var accessToken = azureServiceTokenProvider.GetAccessTokenAsync(managementApiUrl, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx").Result;
            
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);

    // Call Post Method
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/xxxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/simpleLinuxVM/runCommand?api-version=2021-03-01", body);

    // Fetch Result
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        string finalResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Result:", finalResponse.ToString()));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("The request failed with status code: {0}", response.StatusCode));
  
        string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Console.WriteLine(responseContent);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the code you have written here

```cs
script = new List<string> {"ls"}
```

"ls" will be considered as a string in list for "script" object. Thats the reason why you aren't getting any result though there is s Success status.

I found a similar [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329423/passing-arguments-to-a-shell-script-from-c-sharp-process) related to your question. For that you can make myscript. sh run using below code.

```cs
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.FileName = "YourFile.exe";
startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.Arguments = "";//Arguments should be here
using (Process exeProcess = Process.Start(startInfo))
{
    exeProcess.WaitForExit();
}
```

and use  **exeProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();**  to get the results.